# How do I use Expect to connect with SSH?

Tags: perl, expect

In my program I use [Expect](http://p3rl.org/Expect) to run `ssh`. My program is

```
$argument="root@10.2.2.2";
$exp->spawn("ssh $argument") or die "Cannot spawn ssh to ip $ssh_ip_address\n";
```

But even if it is not able to spawn `ssh` it is not printing `Cannot spawn ssh to ip $ssh_ip_address`. Can you please help me understand why it does give the error message?

Comment: That program does not even compile. `Array found where operator expected… syntax error at …, near "root@10"` Post your real code. - While you are waiting for replies to this question, perhaps use the time to go over [your question list](http://stackoverflow.com/users/73181/shayam) and [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#When_you_have_decided_which_answer_is_the_most_helpful_to_you,_mark_it_as_the_accepted_answer) some more answers.

Comment: I really dono how to accpet the answers..

Comment: I linked you already to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): click on the check mark to the left of the answer so it becomes green. You have done this already a couple of times, remember?

Comment: spawn will only fail if the command cannot run. An error returned by the command would not cause spawn to fail.  Also you should run spawn like you would system, i.e. $exp->spawn($command, @arguments);

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you used double quotes for your `$argument` declaration, which means that variables will be interpolated in its contents. `@10` will be evaluated to the contents of the array `@10`.  Use single quotes to avoid interpolation.

And remember, always *always* include `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of every Perl module, program and script. It will save you from lots of hidden errors and therefore a lot of headache. :)

For anything more, you'll have to post the actual code you're running.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Expect directly, run either [Net::SSH::Expect](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SSH-Expect) (which wraps up SSH interaction with Expect) or [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-OpenSSH) (whuch doesn't use Expect, and advises against it).  Also, always use strict and warnings.